# How to wrap sibling text of elements with tag using javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to transform:

```html
<span class="element">
  <span class="word">The</span>
  <span class="word">car</span>
  <span class="word">speed</span>
  <span class="word">was</span>
  40km/s
</span>
```

into:

```html
<span class="element">
  <span class="word">The</span>
  <span class="word">car</span>
  <span class="word">speed</span>
  <span class="word">was</span>
  <span class="data">40km/s</span>
</span>
```

How could I change it using javascript or jquery?

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`.contents()`](https://api.jquery.com/contents/) and [`.last()`](https://api.jquery.com/last/) to select target text from end of `.element` and use [`.wrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) to wrap it with `span` tag.

```js
$(".element").contents().last().wrap("<span class='data'></span>");
```

```css
.data{color:blue}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="element">
  <span class="word">The</span>
  <span class="word">car</span>
  <span class="word">speed</span>
  <span class="word">was</span>
  40km/s
</span>
```